# How to create internal Linking inside CHM help file

Tags: html-helper, chm, helpfile

I am creating a Help file for a C# program i wrote. i am using Windows HTML helper to create the CHM file. how can i go about creating links within this to jump me to another page or another part of the CHM file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links inside a CHMis nothing CHM specific, they are just use normal HREF urls.

The only thing you want to do is make sure they all have relative paths relative to your CHM root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually in each of source HTML files or use any of the help authoring tools available. [Helpinator](http://www.helpinator.com) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It have not come across any way to create internal links in a help file.

A way to do so is to create hyperlinks in a word document and then create the help file. It will work properly as you want.

If you encounter any issues, let me know!